Is it possible to get my current Google Workspace subscription plan info via Admin SDK API or any other API?
I have found something similar in these APIs:
https://developers.google.com/admin-sdk/reseller/v1/how-tos/concepts
https://cloud.google.com/billing/docs/reference/rest
https://developers.google.com/android-publisher/api-ref/rest/v3/purchases.subscriptions
But I'm not really sure that this is what I exactly need. I wonder if it is actually possible to get any info about the subscription plan via any of those available endpoints
